# How to check the matching of characters between 2 columns?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have two columns, and I want to check if they match between 4 or more characters regardless of the position of the array, if they match then create a column that is OK if it matches and KO otherwise.

How can I do this in PYTHON or SQL LITE?

Example:

DATASET WITH ;

```
Street 1;Street 2
ASENSIO Y TOLEDO 15;AVILA 9
AVILA 9;AVILA 9
FISTERRA S/N;FINISTERRE S/N - SAN ROQUE
PASEO DEL PUER;PASEO DEL PUERTO SN
PASEO DEL PUER;PASEO DEL PUERTO SN
LA UNION 2;LA UNION 2
ALEGRIA 14;LA UNION 2
```

Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYLcg.png

Code:

```
def dataet():
df_dataset= pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Documents/DATASET2.CSV", sep=';')

print(df_dataset.columns.values)
query = """
        SELECT INSTR(street 1, street 2)
        FROM df_dataset
    """

result= pdsql.sqldf(query)
print(result)
```

Comment: Hint : You can do it whith a U.D.F. in sql, just loop the first string and check with `INSTR()` function if the character is in the second string.

Answer (score 1):

In python you can use `set`s to get unique characters in a string and then `&` sets from `Street 1` and `Street 2` to get their union. I'm also removing spaces from the matching list, you don't want to count them, right?

```
df['count'] = ['OK' if len(set(x) & set(y) - set(' ')) >= 4 else 'KO' for x, y in zip(df['Street 1'].fillna(''), df['Street 2'].fillna(''))]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
              Street 1                    Street 2 count
0  ASENSIO Y TOLEDO 15                     AVILA 9    KO
1              AVILA 9                     AVILA 9    OK
2         FISTERRA S/N  FINISTERRE S/N - SAN ROQUE    OK
3       PASEO DEL PUER         PASEO DEL PUERTO SN    OK
4       PASEO DEL PUER         PASEO DEL PUERTO SN    OK
5           LA UNION 2                  LA UNION 2    OK
6           ALEGRIA 14                  LA UNION 2    KO
```

**Update:** If you're looking for the length of the longest common substring between `Street 1` and `Street 2`:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

z = df.fillna('')
z['count'] = [len(x[m.a:m.a+m.size].replace(' ', '')) for x, m in
     [(x, SequenceMatcher(None, x, y).find_longest_match(0, len(x), 0, len(y)))
     for x, y in zip(z['Street 1'], z['Street 2'])]]

z['match'] = ['OK' if x >= 4 else 'KO' for x in z['count']]

print(z)
```

Output:

```
              Street 1                    Street 2  count match
0  ASENSIO Y TOLEDO 15                     AVILA 9      1    KO
1              AVILA 9                     AVILA 9      6    OK
2         FISTERRA S/N  FINISTERRE S/N - SAN ROQUE      6    OK
3       PASEO DEL PUER         PASEO DEL PUERTO SN     12    OK
4       PASEO DEL PUER         PASEO DEL PUERTO SN     12    OK
5           LA UNION 2                  LA UNION 2      8    OK
6           ALEGRIA 14                  LA UNION 2      1    KO
7     JARILLO 7 BO IZD                SAN AMBROSIO      1    KO
8     STREET AVE PARRA              PARRA STREET 4      6    OK
9              PARRA 4                                  0    KO
```

Comment: Yes, I do not want to delete the spaces.
I tried to read the entire file either in excel or .csv and it gives me an error.

Can it be because in some column there is a null?

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: Yes, most likely it's exactly the case, you may have some `NA`s there. The easiest would be to just add `fillna('')`s. I've updated my answer with this. `NA`s will always produce `KO` since they can never match anything else on 4 characters, hope that's how it's supposed to be in your logic

Comment: If I added "***" to the nulls.
Checking the output of the script if we have for example:

These do not share similar characters:

JARILLO 7 BO IZD || SAN AMBROSIO = OK

Here PARRA shares 5 characters and KO comes out:

PARRA 4 || PARRA 5 = KO

Comment: For "JARILLO 7 BO IZD || SAN AMBROSIO" you have an overlap of "R, B, I, O, A", which is 5 characters >= 4, so it should be OK

Comment: For "PARRA 4 || PARRA 5" we're counting unique characters, so it's only "P, R, A". Do you want to count them multiple times? What count would you expect to get for "PARA || PARRA"?

Comment: For JARILLO 7 BO IZD || SAN SAMBROSIO, if we compare the chains KO should appear, regardless if there is overlap.                                                                     For "PARRA 4 || PARRA 5" we're counting unique characters, so it's only "P, R, A". Do you want to count them multiple times? What would you expect to get for "PARA || PARRA"?

Here we see that PARRA = PARRA should be OK.

That is, you must compare the characters independently of the position.

Comment: Can you please describe how you compare them in more detail? My understanding was that you check how many unique characters found in 1 are also present in 2, but maybe what you're trying to do is different...

Comment: Yes.

I compare column_1 PARRA 4 with column_2 PARRA 5,
The condition is for example minimum 4 characters.
In the column as there are 4 characters lame: PARR and if in column_2 there exists that concidence the result is an OK.
In this example it is agreed that PARR is in the first position of the array, the idea is that it compares 4 characters independently of the position.

For example:

STREET AVE PARRA || PARRA STREET 4 = OK
PARRA 4 || PARRA 4 = OK
JARILLO 7 BO IZD || SAN AMBROSIO = KO

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I see, so I think what you're looking for is the length of the longest common substring between Street 1 and Street 2. Please see my updated answer

Comment: The latest version doesn't count spaces, but also doesn't break the substring on spaces, so `AVILA 9 | AVILA 9` gives a count of 6

Comment: Thanks for your time, the algorithm works, in some cases we detect KO that they are not, but it helps us a lot.

Thank you!!

Comment: @dapdap: Happy to hear that! Would be great if you can accept the answer if it works. And feel free to share some cases where you have KOs and you think you shouldn't - maybe we can make some adjustments to make it work for those cases too

Answer (score 0):

Also using numpy.where():

```
df['res'] = np.where([len(set(x) - set(y))>=4 for x, y in zip(df['Street 1'], df['Street 2'])], 'OK', 'KO')
```